# Error installing openCV for python3 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I tried to install openCV for python3 on Ubuntu 16.04

I used python library on my anaconda virture environment.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D \
PYTHON_LIBRARY=[conda virture env dir]/lib/libpython3.6m.so -D \
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=[conda virture env dir]/include/python3.6m -D \
PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=[conda virture env dir]/bin/python3.6 ..

make 

sudo make install

sudo ldconfig
```

I found the `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` file at `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

and linked the file

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so cv2.so
```

Then I tried to import 'cv2' on python interpreter and I got an error....

[image]

Comment: might be helpful http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we expect all valuable information like code, error message and so on to be **in the question post itself**, not *linked*. Please, [edit] you question post and add error message into it **as text**.

Comment: Compiling it didn't work for me. Do `pip install opencv-python` and `pip install opencv-contrib-python`. This will get you started.